# Trigger Event, when autocomplete completes the password input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a simple form for a login, and I want to display the caption in the fields, as long as they are empty. The problem was, that password-type cannot be changed by JS.

So I took a second input, which is exchanged with the password field, when the password field is empty.

The problem is, if the user enters a username and the browser auto-completes the password field, the password field will not be displayed.
What can I do?

My HTML:

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="/login" class="dialog form">
    <input type="submit" value="GO" />
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" name="username" class="required" title="Username"/>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="required"  />
        <input type="text" value="Password" class="password-title" />
    </div>
    <p class="clear">&nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

My JS (jQuery required):

```
       $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
           var input = $(this);
           
           if(input.val() == "") input.val(input.attr('title'));
           input.bind('click', function(){
               $(this).focus();
               if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title')) $(this).val("");
           });
           input.bind('blur', function(){               
                if($(this).val() == "") $(this).val($(this).attr('title'));
           });
           
        });
        
        $("input[type=password]").each(function(){
            var input = $(this);
            var title = input.next('.password-title');
            
            if(input.val() == "" && title.length > 0){
                title.show();
                input.hide();
            }
            
            title.bind('click', function(){
                title.hide();
                input.show();
                input.focus();
            });
            
            input.bind('blur', function(){
                if($(this).val() == ""){
                    title.show();
                    input.hide();
                }
            });
            
            input.bind('DOMAutoComplete', function(){
                alert("dafuq"); //does not work (tested in Chromeium)
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using placeholder attribute of input element instead. Read more about it: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#The_placeholder_attribute).

Answer (score 0):

```
input.bind('change', function(){
  title.hide();
  input.show();
  input.focus();
});
```